# How can I get a Compressed Sparse Row matrix such as from scipy.csr_matrix() in JAVA

Tags: java, python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Is there a libary available with an equal function for java? If not, how can I implement this?

Link to the scipy sparse.csr_matrix function: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html

Thanks in advance

Comment: The scipy sparse module is based on `numpy`.  What math array library are you using in `java`?

Comment: How much of the csr implementation do you need.  It's one thing to represent sparse data, it's another to do fast math such as matrix multiplication.  In the scipy case the later is done with C code.

Comment: I need it for a gradient calculation. A step of this contains matrix multiplications. I m new in this area, so my question is: do I need these CSR only to get faster results (because less computing power) and can I use the regular / normal matrix as well?

Comment: In numpy a matrix has to be very large (in shape), and very sparse, for the csr multiply to beat np.dot.   Especially if conversion to and from sparse is included in the timing.